# Yii PHP Rest URL Pattern match with related models in URL

Tags: php, regex, rest, yii, url-routing

I'm trying to create a URL Rule which would allow to fetch related models. Such as this this URL:

> /api/user/1/friends

I'd get a collection "friends" for user with ID 1

For this I've written this regex:

```
api(\/\w+\/\d+)*(\/\w+)*
```

Which matches all of these URL patterns

> api/
>
> api/user
>
> api/user/1
>
> api/user/1/friends

But, when I write a rule out of this in Yii URL Manager. I get an exception for the following rule, which says:

Rule:

```
array('api/list', 'pattern'=>'`api(/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>)*(/<model:\w+>)*`', 'GET')
```

CException:

> The URL pattern "`api(/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>)*(/<model:\w+>)*`" for route "api/list" is not a valid regular expression.

The issue here is that there are two same named captures `<model:\w+>`.

Is there a way to capture a list of all the models and related models?

Edit:

After, playing a little bit, I've managed to eliminate the exception but I'm still not getting a complete list of models and relations.

New Rule:

> array('api/list', 'pattern'=>'api(`/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>)*(/<relation:\w+>)+`', 'GET')

Using this I get the following array in $_GET:

> URL: api/user/1/friends/2/profile
>
> Array ( [model] => friends [id] => 2 [relation] => profile )
> Only the last occurrence of model and id is returned in the match.

Regards

Comment: What is your desired result array? Like this: `Array ([user] => 1 [model] => friends [id] => 2 [relation] => profile )` ?

Comment: @devOp since it uses *preg_match*, it'd be very convenient if the returned array is something like this:
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => api/user/1/friends/2/profile
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /user/1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => /friends/2
            [1] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => /profile
            [1] => 20
        )

)`
As it'd return with the flag PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE.

Comment: @devOp or the final returned $_GET array be: 
`Array ( [user] => 1 [friends] => 2 [profile] => null )`

Comment: Is this working for your requirements? `array('api/<action>', 'pattern' => 'api/<action:\w+>/<user:\d+>/friends/<friends:\d+>/<relation:\w+>', 'GET')`